# Using Sequelize to upload .CSV file to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-sql

If I want to upload .csv file (VIA Get Request to url) to MySQL using nodejs / sequelize, is there a way for me to auto-detect the schema and not define all the columns for me to bulk insert into the cloud sql database?

Answer (score 0):

there may exist a sequelize way, but i would just ask the mysql server directly about the structure of its database.

for exemple this will give you the tables of the database XXXXXX

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`= 'XXXXXX'
```

similarly this will return the available columns in a table

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`, `COLUMN_NAME`, `COLLATION_NAME`, `COLUMN_DEFAULT`, `IS_NULLABLE`, `DATA_TYPE`, `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`, `EXTRA`, `COLUMN_COMMENT` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='XXXXXX' and `TABLE_NAME` = 'YYYYYY'
```

Comment: my table in the database is empty right now and I want to insert the csv contents into mysql

Comment: you want to autodetect columns in csv to create columns in sql ? the firstline of you csv may be a title line. If yes you can use this line to generate the column names. and you will still need to guess the correct data format. i dont think a lib does it for you. would be way easier to hardcode it